# Call to reactive expression doesn't return - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I seems like the call to d() doesn't return anything and it lasts forever when the app starts and executes the code in renderText. Why so?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("but","Click"),
  textOutput("ui_out")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  d <- eventReactive(input$but, {
    100
  })
  output$ui_out <- renderText({
    print("in")
    d()
    print("out")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: do you want to print "in" and "out" as well, or is that debugging code?

Comment: just debugging code

Comment: if you remove them it works for me

Comment: I removed them but what I wanted to see is the button + the text 100. It's just the button

Comment: the last argument within pretty much any function in `shiny` should be the object you're trying to return, here you're returning `print("out")`

Comment: Yes. It was just for debugging. And why on the screen when the app starts isn't showing "out"?

Comment: I thought that I could write code like if(is.null(d())) {...} , but I can't, just because d() lasts forever at the beginning of the app...

Comment: A solution would be to turn eventReactive into reactive: 
d <- reactive({
    input$but;
    100
  }). But I don't understand why isn't this happening with eventReactive...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1125) and more concretely [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1125#issuecomment-279606251).
It's not about lasting forever. It was a silent error.
The solution is using ignoreNULL = FALSE.